# Moving object fast appears to be shaking/vibrating in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using cocos2d-x 3.4, When I try to move object fast on screen in cocos2d-x,it appears like shaking, I am using MoveTo, function,and my object moves very fast. How can I make this move action smooth.
Please help me!
 Here is my code:-

```
Vector<FiniteTimeAction*> actionVector;




    CCLOG("inside movePlayerOnGrid %zd",playerPosArray.size());
    for (int i=0;  i < playerPosArray.size(); i++) {

        auto  moveAction                    =   MoveTo::create(MOVING_TIME,playerPosArray[i]);

        actionVector.pushBack(moveAction);

         if(isDarkMode){


            auto  moveActionForDarkMode2        =   MoveTo::create(MOVING_TIME,playerPosArray[i]);
            actionVectorForDarkMode2.pushBack(moveActionForDarkMode2);

         }
    }

    if(actionVector.size() > 0){

        Sequence    *seq        =   Sequence::create(actionVector);
        player->runAction(seq);
```

here player is my object(Sprite)

Comment: It will be better if you can share code snippet related to the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question along with code please help with that

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the value of MOVING_TIME. In the cases that I have encountered, increasing this reduces the shaking.

Comment: thanks! But increasing the value of MOVING_TIME, will not help,because object should move in very fast motion.... Please help if any other solution is there..

Comment: In that case I suggest that you don't use CCMove and move the object manually in the update loop. I also suggest you implement a fixed time step as is done for physics engines. You can read more about imementing fixed time step here: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/